# Recharts chart not updating when using setInterval to periodically append new data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I'm trying to set up a web page that adds a score onto a line chart every 2 minutes and it doesn't seem to be working.

The chart that I am using is the line chart from the Recharts, and the initial value of scoreData is an empty list and the initial form of {time} is {h:0, m:0, s:0}.

I am using context and hooks so that the page won't stop counting even if the user for some reason temporarily visits other pages that I will be creating.

The code that I wrote down is as follows;

```
const Timer = () => {
  const {
    scoreData,
    setScoreData,
    time,
    setTime,
    interv,
    setInterv,
  } = useContext(BaseContext);

const addNewData = () => {
    setScoreData([...score, {Some New data}])
}

const start = () => {
    run();
    setInterv(setInterval(run, 1000));
 };

var updatedS = time.s,
    updatedM = time.m,
    updatedH = time.h;

  const run = () => {
    updatedS++;
    if (updatedS === 60) {
      updatedM++;
      updatedS = 0;
      if (updatedM % 2 == 0) {
        addNewData();
        console.log(scoreData.length);
      }
    }
    if (updatedM === 60) {
      updatedH++;
      updatedM = 0;
    }
    return setTime({
      s: updatedS,
      m: updatedM,
      h: updatedH,
    });
  };

return (
<div>
// The code of the line chart goes in here.

<button onClick={start}>Start</button>

<button onClick={addNewData}>Test Button</button>

</div>
)
```

According to the above code, a new data should be added to the list every two minutes, but the chart never showed any changes.

When I confirmed the status of the scoreData by using console.log(scoreData.length), the console just showed 0, which means the data is not being appended into the list.

So I tried a different approach by making a Test Button that manually adds a new data and it worked just fine; the list was filled with new data every time I pushed it.

In this case, what can I do to make the chart receive the data periodically in accordance to the time that I set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, unfortunately with react hooks you cannot use `setInterval` in the way you are using it. The problem is related to hooks itself. According to your code example, you want to add a new data to your `scoreData` each second. So you call `useInterval` that launches `run` that, `if (updatedM % 2 == 0)`, calls `addNewData` that finally adds value to your `scoreData`.

Unfortunately, with hooks you are not sure that `scoreData` is already updated with data you added in previuos `setInterval`. Why? Because hooks are async!

How to solve this? With another hook, in particular a custom hook!

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-examples-lolsk?file=/src/charts/ScatterChart.js) a working example.
Lets see my custom hook `useInterval`:

```
function useInterval(callback, delay) {
    const savedCallback = useRef();

    // Remember the latest callback.
    useEffect(() => {
      savedCallback.current = callback;
    }, [callback]);

    // Set up the interval.
    useEffect(() => {
      function tick() {
        savedCallback.current();
      }
      if (delay !== null) {
        let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
        return () => clearInterval(id);
      }
    }, [delay]);
  }
```

As you can see inside my custom hook I use 2 `useEffect`: 1 to remember the latest `useInterval` callback (using `useRef`); and the other one is used to set the delay of the `setInterval` (this  last `useEffect` returns a `clearInterval` to cancel the last `setInterval`).

Then I can call `useInterval` inside my component:

```
useInterval(() => {
if (sampling) {
  let result = _.cloneDeep(list1);
  result.push({
    x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
  });
  console.log(result);
  setlist1(result);
}
}, 1000);
```

`list1` is my array of values (your `scoreData`) and `sampling` is a bool state variable that I use to run/stop insertion of new vlaues into `list1`.

Finally, my `return`:

```
return (
    <div>
      <ScatterChart
        width={600}
        height={400}
        margin={{ top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20 }}
      >
        <CartesianGrid />
        <XAxis type="number" dataKey={"x"} />
        <YAxis type="number" dataKey={"y"} />
        <Tooltip cursor={{ strokeDasharray: "3 3" }} />
        <Legend />
        <Scatter
          name="values"
          data={list1}
          fill="#8884d8"
          line
          shape="circle"
        />
      </ScatterChart>
      <button onClick={start}>
        {sampling ? "Stop sampling" : "Start sampling"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```

I used `ScatterChart` (graphically equal to `LineChart`) and a button to start/stop data sampling.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I totally lack understanding of Hooks and async systems but thanks to your thorough explanation, I think I'm getting a bit more closer to React systems :)

Comment: Glad to ear that! Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `setScoreData([...score, {Some New data}])` should be `setScoreData([...scoreData, {Some New data}])`

Your `setInterval` receives a closure with fixed `scoreData` and keeps calling it. So `setScoreData([...scoreData, {Some New data}])` always sets the same data.
In your case it is better to fix this issue with [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook:

```
  const {
    scoreData,
    setScoreData,
    time,
    setTime,
    interv,
    setInterv,
  } = useContext(BaseContext);
  const scoreDataRef = useRef(scoreData);
  scoreDataRef.current = scoreData;

  const addNewData = () => {
    setScoreData([...scoreDataRef.current, {Some New data}])
  }
```

Test button works because it gets a new closure on each render.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried the code out and saw that the graph was updating every now and then, but when I put the console.log(scoreData) inside the addNewData function, the console was showing an empty list. Not sure why this is happening when one could clearly see the chart updating...